# $-\Delta u = f$ in $L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$ (as opposed to $H^{-1}(\Omega)$)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

Why does nobody consider the equation $-\Delta u = f$ in the space $L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$?

Eg. given $f \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ find a solution $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1_0(\Omega))$ such that
$$\int_0^T \int_\Omega \nabla u(t) \nabla v(t) = \int_0^T\int_\Omega f(t)v(t)$$
for all $v \in L^2(0,T;H^1_0(\Omega))$. This solution exists by Poincare's inequality which applies on a.e. time:
$$\int_\Omega |\nabla v(t)|^2 \geq C\int_\Omega |v(t)|^2\quad\text{for a.e. $t$}$$
and then we apply Lax-Milligram.

Of course I know that Poison's equation is an elliptic equation, and Bochner space is for parabolic equations. But is there anything wrong with what I wrote?

Comment: There is no time derivative or dependence in $-\Delta f=u$, so why should we look for a function depending on time?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis But I want $f$ to be time-dependent. (I don't want a time derivative $u_t$ in the equation either).

Comment: There is nothing that can stop you.